# Analysis of differential transcript usage (DTU)

Tags: rna-seq, transcriptome, software-recommendation

Recent breakthroughs in bioinformatics tools for quantification (e.g.
[Cufflinks](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/)/[Kallisto](http://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/)/[Salmon](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon) etc.) and tools which can identify differential transcript usage (DTU) (e.g. [DRIMSeq](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DRIMSeq.html), [Cufflinks](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/) etc.) mean that from RNA-seq data we can now relatively easy obtain a genome wide analysis of transcripts that are differentially used betwen conditions.

What can you use these results for? What systematic analysis does this transcript level data enable?

Comment: I would recommend to remove the software-recommendation tag. Here you don't ask for a tool to analyze this type of data, but what can be done analyzing this kind of data.

Comment: But I'm also asking for tools that can do it...?

Answer (score 4):

I will take the liberty of giving one possible answers to my own question – but I’m very interested in other answers.

One analysis type that such data enables is the analysis of transcript switches with predicted potential consequences.

I myself have recently developed such a tool called [IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR](http://bioconductor.org/packages/IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR/). IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR enables statistical identification (via [DRIMSeq](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DRIMSeq.html)) of isoform switches with predicted functional consequences. The consequences analyzed can be chosen from a long list which includes gain/loss of protein domains, signal peptides changes in NMD sensitivity etc. The R package also enables easy visualization of isoform switches along with their consequences and it directly supports the output of [Cufflinks/Cuffdiff](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/), [RSEM](http://deweylab.github.io/RSEM/), [Salmon](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon) and [Kallisto](http://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/).

Apart from enabling identification of interesting examples switch identification also enables systematic analysis of what genes are affected. For inspiration I will recommend [one of my own articles](http://mcr.aacrjournals.org/content/early/2017/06/02/1541-7786.MCR-16-0459) (describing results obtained with IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR) as well Hector et al’s [recent paper](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/09/21/076653) (which is not using IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR). Of particular interest and finesse is Hector’s analysis of how isoform switches can disrupt protein-protein interactions.

Looking forward to hear more ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this has been done, is common, or are research lines, but here is what I think can be done with transcripts' differences (aside from comparing the change of the expression of each transcript):

Having the different transcripts, enables us to study also the relation between transcripts, which are co-expressed together or differently co-expressed. Maybe at the individual level the switch between transcripts of a gene is not related to a condition, but together with other transcripts it is.

Transcripts usage could be also linked to structural or genomic changes. Either short/small changes or big. At genomic level SNP, inversions or methylation..., or structural changes such as compression of a region, different distances between chromosomes/regions...

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "differently co-expressed" ?

Comment: The way a transcript (or a gene) is expressed with other transcripts can change between conditions. If in a condition transcript A is co-expressed with B, C and D, in another condition it can be co-expressed with D, E and F. See this [paper](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-11-497)

Answer (score 1):

Additional insights can frequently be made in research by studying things at a lower level. By peeling back the higher layers, effects can be seen that are hidden (or reversed) when looking at aggregate data. This is generally referred to as [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

We know that RNA is functional at an isoform/transcript level, and in some cases the expression of different transcripts from the same gene can have different biologically-relevant outcomes. By looking at transcript-level information, even if the transcripts for a gene average out to be a similar level between different treatment conditions, variation at an individual transcript level can still be discovered. This is important when looking at differential expression of *populations* of cells, because it can clue researchers into finding out that a particular cell sub-population might be of interest; single cells typically will only produce single isoforms for each gene at a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this post is rather old but there has been some development in the field and [this 2019 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/labs/pmc/articles/PMC6178912.2/) might be a good resource for interested individuals.